# Can't access localhost from Android device for test API

Tags: apache2, android, localhost

I write my web services in Django, everything is OK when I test my API in postman (on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`). But when I try to use Retrofit to connect `http://192.168.43.115:8000` I cannot. This is the error:

> message:java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to 
>   /192.168.43.115 (port 8000) from /192.168.232.2 (port 50628) after 
>   10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused

Comment: The `127.0.0.1:8000` in the output of `lsof` means that your program is listening only on the 127.0.0.1 interface, not on 192.168.43.255.

Comment: I cannot use    127.0.0.1:8000. failed to connect...

Comment: Yes. You must make your application listen on all interfaces, not just on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: could you please explain more? How can  I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I use ipv6 with this command:

```
python manage.py runserver [::]:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Node.js API. the The solution was to stop the firewall service by running:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

(Note I'm using Fedora 30.)

That way I can access my Rest API in `localhost` via an Android phone.